# Kotlin Coroutines for Parallelism and How long i can have the coroutine open?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a need to parallel hit 100 sqs to poll messages and hit another service. How i imagined is starting a 100 coroutines and running it forever so that each coroutines will hit the SQS in parallel and based on the result, i might hit another microservice. I have few question on using coroutines like this

1. Can i keep my coroutine open forever, i.e the launched coroutine will have a loop which runs forever to get the message from SQS and calls a different Microservice.
2. Is there any possibility that my coroutine gets killed(I have proper try/catch for the exceptions thrown from the Microservice and SQS in between when i do such non ending operation, if so how it's been handled via Kotlin.
3. Is there any other way to many this parallelism work? My application is a Kotlin/Spring boot application.

Can someone please guide on this scenario

Comment: Could you elaborate what is a SQS?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri "[Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) (SQS) is a fully managed message queuing service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, there's nothing preventing you from having a coroutine run forever.
2. Nothing in the Kotlin Coroutines infrastructure will want to kill your coroutine.

I think you asked questions that have easy answers, but they don't necessarily cut to the point of what you're doing. How long-running jobs behave depends a lot on the wider infrastructure, and the main question to ask is about the fault tolerance of the execution environment.